# Insert into mysql by incrementing a number by 3

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table to store user's height. My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE height (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  feets_and_inches VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  centimeters INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My question is I need to insert centimeters to this table like this `91,94,97,100..... and upto 241`

Can I know is there a way to insert this value using a loop other than doing it manually.

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are operating in MySQL, you can create a loop from 91 to 241 like this like this:

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE CENTIMETERINSERT()
   BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;
    DECLARE max INT;
    SET count=91;
    SET max= 241;
    WHILE(count < max) DO
        -- Run your insert here, replace my example select statement
        SELECT count;
        SET count=(count+3);
    END WHILE;
END $$

CALL CENTIMETERINSERT() $$
```

Comment: Whoops. ;) I didn't see that he incremented by 3, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I just edited it slightly so you can run it directly in the command line -- just replace the comment with your insert.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I know is there a way to insert this value using a loop other than doing it manually.

One way would be

```
$i=91;
while($i<=241)
{
    // insert $i as centimeters in a query
    $i+=3;
}
```

Comment: Can we do it by  mysql itself?

Comment: Yes, http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/using-mysql-stored-procedure-to-create-sample-data/

Comment: @MCC why did you include PHP as a tag if you don't want to use PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in mysql

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 91;
        WHILE (i<=241) DO
               //write your insert statement
               SET i=i+3;
        END WHILE;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use nearly any type of loop to do this. I would recommend a for loop as follows:

```
for ($i=91; $i <= 241; $i +=3){
   //SQL insert code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a small procedure for that and call it whenever you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_centimeters`()

BEGIN

DECLARE counter int DEFAULT 91;

WHILE (counter < 242) DO
       INSERT INTO height(centimeters) VALUES (counter);
       SET counter =  counter + 3;
END WHILE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$j = 91; 

 for($i=$j; $i<=241; $i++){

    // echo $i;
    // insert the below variable into table   
    $insert_it = $i; 

    ///  Put insert sql query below example is:
    // mysql_query("insert into tbl(`height`) values('$insert_it')");
    $i=$i+2;
}
```